# loop over a bunch of H5 files and creating a new list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import os

import h5py

os.chdir('C:\Users\dew')

file_names = ['3DSND_12MAY2016_0000_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_0100_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_0200_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_0300_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_0500_L1B_SA1.h5', 
            '3DSND_12MAY2016_0600_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_0600_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_0700_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_0800_L1B_SA1.h5',
             '3DSND_12MAY2016_0900_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_1000_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_1200_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_1300_L1B_SA1.h5', 
            '3DSND_12MAY2016_1400_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_1500_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_1700_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_1900_L1B_SA1.h5', 
            '3DSND_12MAY2016_2000_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_2100_L1B_SA1.h5', '3DSND_12MAY2016_2200_L1B_SA1.h5']

new = list()

new = list()

for file_name in file_names:
    print file_name
    new = (h5py.File(file_name, 'r'))
    print new
```

On running this, got the following output:

```
3DSND_12MAY2016_0000_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0000_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r+)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0100_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0100_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0200_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0200_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0300_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0300_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0500_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0500_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0600_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0600_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0600_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0600_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0700_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0700_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0800_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0800_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_0900_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_0900_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_1000_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_1000_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_1200_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_1200_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_1300_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_1300_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_1400_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_1400_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_1500_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_1500_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_1700_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_1700_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_1900_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_1900_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_2000_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_2000_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_2100_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_2100_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
3DSND_12MAY2016_2200_L1B_SA1.h5
<HDF5 file "3DSND_12MAY2016_2200_L1B_SA1.h5" (mode r)>
```

I did this, in order to read a bunch of H5 files together and to assign them to another list. unfortunately, the new list shows only a single file included in it when I run it.

but while calling the new list separately,returns only single h5 file.

new

#output

Comment: If I understand correctly you want `new` to contain a list of the HDF5 file objects, and so just need to replace `new =...` with `new.append(h5py.File(file_name, 'r'))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question.
If you only want to copy the names in another new list this is how it works

```
new = []
for file_name in file_names:
    new.append(file_name)
```

You can find a useful documentation on lists here:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Or do you want to read the contents of your HDF5-Files and add them to one HDF5-File? Then a small info what's inside the HDF5-Files and what you want as result will be needed.
Basically you have to read each dataset in your bunch of HDF5-Files and add them to another one. 
Or do you want to read one or more datasets from your HDF5-Files and add these to     a list? In this example each h5-File has a Dataset called 'A'.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
new = []
for file_name in file_names:
    f=h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
    dset=f['A']
    Data=np.copy(dset) #copy the content
    new.append(Data)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Copying with an explicit loop is usually unnecessary. `new = list(filenames)` or (if `filenames` is known to be a `list` already, as in this case) `new = filenames[:]` would accomplish the shallow copy much more succinctly. That said, the question doesn't seem to need to copy a `list`, so not sure why that's the first part of your answer...